# Regex: Find usename inside a url

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm struggling with creating the correct REGEX pattern to find a username string in the middle of a url. In short, I'm working in Powershell and pulling down a webpage and scraping out the "li" elements. I write this to a file so I have a bunch of lines like this:

```
<LI><A HREF="/grouplist/expand-user/jimmysmith">Smith, Jimmy</A>&nbsp;
```

The string I need is the "jimmysmith" part, and every line will have a different username, no longer than eight alpha characters. My current pattern is this:

```
(<(.|\n)+?>)|(&nbsp;)
```

and I can use a "-replace $pattern" in my code to grab the "Smith, Jimmy" part. I have no idea what I'm doing, and any success in getting what I did get was face-roll-luck.

After using several online regex helpers I'm still stuck on how to just get the "string after the third "/" and up-to but not including the last quote.

Thank you for any assistance you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regex:

[`[^\/"]+(?=">.*<\/A>)`](https://regex101.com/r/bhLy8d/2)

This wll capture the last string in `href` attribute of `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use an HTML parser instead. Try:

```
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$source = '<LI><A HREF="/grouplist/expand-user/jimmysmith">Smith, Jimmy</A>&nbsp;'
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($source)
$html.links | % nameprop
```

> jimmysmith

Comment: `($html.links | select nameprop).nameprop` also

Comment: I'd suggest using the term "html parser" since parsing html with regex is a terrible idea.  Also: `$html.links.nameprop` is equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 For some reason that didn't work for me, and I wasn't sure why. It should be equivalent but it wasn't returning data for me.

Comment: Which version of PS? Automatic enumeration wasn't added until v3.  Alternative to what you wrote, I'd use `|% nameprop` (which is equivalent to `| ForEach-Object -MemberName 'nameprop'`)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm using 5.1 - I like that method though, I'll edit. It's a lot cleaner.

Comment: I should have added that I am on a MAC, writing in PowerShell Core 6.1. Sorry for the oversight, but I don't believe I can use "-ComObject". I was using regex since that was the most cross-platform method I could think of.

Comment: Honestly at this point I would create another question and ask how to replicate my answer on Core 6.1. Personally I have no experience with it and can't help you there. @user9245487

Comment: Extraordinary thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Just simply to replace redundant strings.

```
'<LI><A HREF="/grouplist/expand-user/jimmysmith">Smith, Jimmy</A>&nbsp;' -replace ".*user/|`"\>.*"
```

If you have multiple lines, try this:

```
'<LI><A HREF="/grouplist/expand-user/jimmysmith">Smith, Jimmy</A>&nbsp;' -replace "^\<LI.*user/|`"\>.*"
```

Both work, tested.

Comment: I've also tested and this works. I will use this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use double quotes if you're not using any string expansion and you don't need escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question, was contained in this response by Sergio.

Try the following regex:

```
[^\/"]+(?=">.*<\/A>)
```

This will capture the last string in href attribute of `<a>` tag.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking on the [check mark ✓](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)